# Undefined variable on userdata

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm using codeIgniter to developing a website.
This website has a view sidebar and i call on view header with

`<?php $this->load->view('sidebar');`,

then in another view i call header by using `<?php $this->load->view('header');`
On sidebar i'm loading the session variables by

```
$papel = $this->session->userdata('papel');
$logado = $this->session->userdata('logado');
```

On sidebar it fits perfectly but in other pages like it's doesn't working anymore.
I'm already tried recalling the session variables and got the same results.

ps.: It's alerady autoloaded

Comment: is the session lib loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Load session library in autoload:

1. Open autoload.php file located in application/config/autoload.php
2. Update $autoload['libraries'] variable

`$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'email', 'session');`

Answer (score 0):

Load session in autoload.php found in config folder.

```
  $autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');
```

Plus to make a session you have to set it:

```
  $this->session->set_userdata('session_name', 'value of the session');
```

Then calling it:

```
  $this->session->userdata('session_name');
```

Comment: I'm already did this, but it still don't working 
`$newdata = array(
                'papel'  => $query->row()->papel,
                'login'  => $query->row()->login,
                'logado' => TRUE
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);`